# Trying to install oAuth package using composer

Tags: oauth, composer-php

I'm trying to install the following using composer:

https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib

I tried using:

> "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3"

but that didn't work, the version being used now was something I found online that supposedly works.

When I try to run the following composer install commmand I get a message saying that the package couldn't be found.  It doesn't appear in the composer.json file (not sure if its meant to).  This is the first time I've tried to install this so any tips on getting this working would be much appreciated.

> php composer.phar install
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package lusitanian/oauth 1.0.0 could not be found.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>      see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.
>
> Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

```
{
"name": "lusitanian/oauth",
"description": "PHP 5.3+ oAuth 1/2 Library",
"keywords": ["oauth", "authentication", "authorization", "security"],
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "David Desberg",
        "email": "david@daviddesberg.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Pieter Hordijk",
        "email": "info@pieterhordijk.com"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "0.1.*@dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/http-foundation": "~2.1",
    "predis/predis": "0.8.*@dev",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
"suggest": {
    "symfony/http-foundation": "Allows using the Symfony Session storage backend.",
    "predis/predis": "Allows using the Redis storage backend.",
    "ext-openssl": "Allows for usage of secure connections with the stream-based HTTP client."
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "OAuth": "src",
        "OAuth\\Unit": "tests"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "0.1-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this:

"lusitanian/oauth": "0.1.*@dev"

to this:

"lusitanian/oauth": "1.0.*@dev"

Fixed it :)